# What are the benefits of Using ObjectReader over ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, jackson

How can i Refactor the following code using ObjectReader (Single Instance of ObjectReader)

```
private MessageStructure parseSQSMessageToMessageStructure(final String queueMessage)
    throws IOException, ObjectMapperException {

    JsonNode messageAsJSON = objectMapper.readTree(queueMessage);
    JsonNode messageAsJSONKey = messageAsJSON.get(MESSAGE_JSON_KEY);
    return objectMapper.readValue(messageAsJSONKey.textValue(), MessageStructure.class);
}
```

Comment: Your title and body are asking entirely different questions.

Comment: I have written code using ObjectMapper, I went through several stackOverflow posts where I learnt that ObejctMapper is not thread safe in comparison to ObjectReader.

Comment: Regarding the Code snippet, I want to know how can I Refactor the above code using the ObejctReader instead of ObjectMapper?

Comment: That's somewhat true. It's still not clear what your question is.

Comment: So, you're not asking what the benefits are?

Comment: What are the advantages of using ObjectReader over ObjectMapper?

Comment: if it is recommended to use objectReader, then how can I refactor the above code to use ObjectReader?

Answer (score 1):

As said by @shmosel, your question doesn't match the title.

If you wish to replace instance of  `ObjectMapper` with `ObjectReader`, replace the below line.

From :

```
return objectMapper.readValue(messageAsJSONKey.textValue(), MessageStructure.class);
```

To-be :

```
return objectReader.readValue(messageAsJSONKey.textValue(), MessageStructure.class);
```

The above code snippet assumes `objectReader` is an instance of `ObjectReader` class.

Below is the information I got from JavaDocs of `ObjectReader` regarding its performance.

> Uses "mutant factory" pattern so that instances are immutable   (and
>   thus fully thread-safe with no external synchronization);   new
>   instances are constructed for different configurations.   Instances
>   are initially constructed by {@link ObjectMapper} and can be   reused,
>   shared, cached; both because of thread-safety and because   instances
>   are relatively light-weight.

Hope this helps!